# Cover Letter even without experience on a particular language

Tags: resume, growth

Im a c++ programmer for more than 2years and resigned my work. Now I want to be a freelancer which I will focus on web development using php. What is the proper way to put it on a cover letter? My idea is "Recently quit my job and currently self studying and training to be a web developer. With 2years of experience is c++ programming." but I think it is not convincing to be hired. Is there a way to make it more competitive and convincing?

Comment: "Recently quit my job": ban that !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Junior developer with 2 years experience in C++. Actively improving my PHP skills. Highly motivated to tackle Web projects."

Cite one or more achievements you are proud of.

Comment: perfect.........:)

Answer (score 5):

Cover letter for freelancing?? Never heard of such a thing.

You need marketing materials - a sales pitch, a brochure, a web site, a flier, an email campaign -  but it's nowhere near the same as applying for an employment position. I've never needed a "cover letter" for any freelance work.

I'd also point out that "self studying and training" has no place in freelance marketing materials. Clients aren't interested in what you *want to do* they are interested in *how you can currently help them*. Marketing materials aren't about where you are going, they are about solid, tangible things you've accomplished and how your skills/experience can directly assist a client with a problem they are currently having.